# Rails does not propagate Java exception to ApplicationController

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails website, and the models will cause some backend service.  I have a rescue_from StandardError in the ApplicationController, which can capture rails exception, but cannot capture exceptions from the backend service.

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 rescue_from StandardError do |exception|
   # do something
 end
end
```

Actual controller:

```
class StatementsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    # get statement
    respond_to :js
  end
end
```

If I do "raise 'error message'" inside the show method, then the ApplicationController's rescue method can capture this error. But if the get statement encounters a service exception from the backend service, then the ApplicationController cannot catch it. However, if I do

```
class StatementsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    # get statement
    respond_to :js

    rescue StandardError => e
        # Don't even need to write code here        
  end
end
```

Then the applicationController can catch the java exception. 
I am very new to rails. Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: I understand you are new to Rails. But where did you find Java exception in Rails?

Comment: Because the backend service is written in Java, when ruby calls service objects and something blows up, jruby cannot capture that as expected.

Comment: I came across this article: http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/upgrading-to-jruby-1-7-0
It says "An interesting change in JRuby 1.7.0 is that Java exceptions no longer inherit from ruby Exception. This means that they will not be caught by a standard global rescue. I.e., executing the code below will print ‘Rescued’ under 1.6.8 but will blow up under 1.7.0."

This kind of explains why java exceptions are not propagated back to global rescue.